# Diagnostic loggin

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-diagnostics

I'm trying to set the diagnostic logging for the keyvault.
When I first run this command

```
Get-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting on the keyvault.
```

I get

```
Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
```

Any thoughts on why this may be

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I use the command below, it works fine on my side.

```
Get-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId <ResourceId>
```

[image]

If I use an incorrect `ResourceId`, it will return a `Not Found` error. So I think you could check if your `ResourceId` is correct, you could find it in your keyvault-> Properties in the portal.